# AVAudioPlayer Leaks and warning and at the end my application is crashed

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, audio, avaudioplayer

I am using AVAudioPlayer and i am plying sound again and agian and call this method 100 times in my application.The problem is that i always alooc it but when i am going to release, sound does not work.
what will i do.

```
-(void) ButtonSound
{

NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Button1" 
         ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
[player play];
[fileURL release];

}
```

memory is leak and the application is crashed, I want to allocate player at once and use it again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void) ButtonSound
{

    NSBundle        *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSError         *error;
    NSURL           *audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[mainBundle pathForResource:@"Button1" ofType: @"mp3"]];
    AVAudioPlayer   *player1 = [(AVAudioPlayer*) [AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:&error];
    self.player =   player1;
    [self.player play];
    [player1 release];
}
```

This code is error free and i have not found any leaks by using this code

Answer (score 4):

You can do it something like this

on you header file, declare the player already

```
AVAudioPlayer *buttonSoundPlayer;
```

then on the implementation

```
-(void)playButtonSound {
    if(buttonSoundPlayer == nil) {
       NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Button1" ofType:@"mp3"];
       NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];
       buttonSoundPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
       [fileURL release];
    }
    [buttonSoundPlayer play];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
-(void) ButtonSound
{
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Button1" 
         ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];
    if (player) {
        [player release];
    }
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
    [player play];
    [fileURL release];
}
```

You also need to release `player` in your `dealloc` method.  You also probably need to check whether `player` is already playing when you click the button, and perhaps skip this method if so.

You may also need to `retain` your player object, but that depends on how you've declared it (not shown in your sample).